# Sobject.isSet() not working with Trigger Sobjects

Tags: soql, sobject, fields, null

I'm having an issue with the Sobject method "isSet()". It works well if I query for a record or create a record outright. But does not work correctly for Trigger objects. On trigger objects, isSet only seems to return true if the value for the field is not null.

E.X.

```
Account acc = [Select Null_Field_Test__c from Account LIMIT 1)
System.assert(acc.isSet('Null_Field_Test__c'));

Account accTwo = new Account();
accTwo.Null_Field_Test__c = null;
System.assert(accTwo.isSet('Null_Field_Test__c'));
```

But if I try it in a trigger

```
trigger test on Account (after insert, after update) {
   System.debug('is set: ' + Trigger.new[0].isSet('Null_Field_Test__c'));
}
```

Then I always get false until I put a non-null value into "Null_Field_Test__c". Is this just a bug? Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior might make sense if we take a specific interpretation of the documentation for `isSet()`, which states (at time of writing, Winter '22)

> Returns information about the queried sObject field. Returns true if the sObject field is populated, either by direct assignment or by inclusion in a SOQL query. Returns false if the sObject field is not set. If an invalid field is specified, an SObjectException is thrown.

Since we aren't querying for records in trigger context variables (TCVs for short), and aren't (ourselves) directly setting values on records in TCVs (only records in trigger.new/newmap are editable, and further only in `before` contexts), it's not unreasonable that `isSet()` is returning false.

Given that TCVs pull *all* object fields, I don't think it would be too helpful if `isSet()` would return true for fields on those records. Returning false seems to be a safe default.

I don't think there's a workaround for null fields, but besides that, a simple null check `myRecord.myField__c != null` would suffice.

Comment: That's unfortunate as I have a function that queries a record for more information only if it isn't already set on the record. For trigger objects, it preforms unnecessary queries because of the interaction here. As far as I know, there's also no way to differentiate these Trigger sobjects from non trigger sobjects just using the Sobject record.

Comment: I would be curious if adding a reference to the field causes `isSet` to flip to `true`.